# About definition of NTA domain

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

I'm not an expert in analysis on very rough domains, such as NTA(Nontangentially Accessible Domain).
Here is my question. Usually, NTA domain $\Omega$ is a domain that has inner and outer corkscrew conditions and Harnack chain conditions. This definition was given in the famous paper of Jerison-Kenig. Many authors adapt this definition.

However, when I see a few references (e.g. Kenig's textbook or Daniela De Silva, Ovidiu Savin, *A short proof of Boundary Harnack Inequality*, arXiv:[1909.00062](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00062)), the definition is different. In the case of Silva, it requires to have `Density estimate of the complement': there exist $c>0$ and $R_0>0$ such that
$$|B_r(x)\setminus \Omega|\geq c |B_r(x)|  $$
for all $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ and $0<r\leq R_0$.

Does two definition is equivalent? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The more or less established terminology is, I think, that *NTA* means what Jerison and Kenig introduced. Boundary Harnack inequality holds more generally; if you like, you may consult one of a series of papers by Aikawa on BHI. The other condition has different names: the complement is sometimes said to be *plump* or *fat*. Note that this is not enough for the BHI, other conditions are needed.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for your answer.